# Matrix inversion with variable in {-1,1}

Tags: matrices, inverse

Could you please give me a hint for computing inversion of this matrix?

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & f & g+h\sqrt(2) \\
        0 & i & j \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$

where $f,j \in \mathbb Z;g,h\in \mathbb Q;i\in \{-1,1\}$

I can't use this formula:

$$
\displaystyle (A^{-1})_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}\frac{\mathop{\rm det}\nolimits A_{j,i}}{\mathop{\rm det}\nolimits A}\,
$$

I'm getting this matrix:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & f & 0 \\
        0 & i & j \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

but don't know what to do next, as $i$ is $\{1,-1\}$

Comment: Do you mean "the inverse of the matrix", or inversion of a matrix in another meaning?

Comment: Yes, the inverse, sorry.

Comment: And why can't you use that formula which, in fact, is the famous formula with the adjoint of $\;A\;$ ?

Comment: Have you tried using augmented identity matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Done using augmented matrix:
$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&-fi&-g-h\sqrt2+fij\\0&i&-ij\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Could it be you thought $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ ...just as I did the first time? :)

Comment: $i^2=1$ or $i=\frac1i$ anyway...

Comment: That's true, @peter, yet $\;\frac1i=-i\;$ if $\;i=\sqrt{-1}\,,\,-1\;$ , but **not** if $\;i=1\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & f & g+h\sqrt(2) \\
        0 & i & j \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}^{-1}= \frac1i
        \begin{pmatrix}
        i & -f & \;\;fj-ig-ih\sqrt(2) \\
        0 & \;\;1 & \!-j \\
        0 & \;\;0 & \;\;i \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$